# Python distutils copy_tree fails to update if there are symlinks

Tags: python, distutils

I'm trying to using Python `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree` to copy the contents of one directory to another, and update the files in the destination if they have changed. I'm using the options:

```
copy_tree(src, dst, preserve_symlinks=1, update=1)
```

This works for the initial copy, but fails on all subsequent ones with:

```
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'file1' -> 'test2/file2'
```

Where `file1` is a symlink to `file2`.

I don't need it to update the symlinks. It's fine if it just ignores them the second time around, or blindly overwrites them. But, as it is, it seems impossible to copy a directory containing symlinks in update mode.

Is there some way to do this using this tool? Is there a better tool to use, or will I need to create my own?

Platform details:

CentOS Linux 7.5
Anaconda Python 3.6.6

Comment: good question. I guess I'd monkeypatch `os.symlink` before calling `copy_tree` with an error prone version (skip existing symlinks or remove and recreate them), then revert `os.symlink` to the original function after `copy_tree` finishes. Or just call `rsync` via `subprocess.Popen` :-)

Comment: I'm actually writing this for the purpose of replacing old code that used the `rsync` method. I needed more control over the way things were being synced. The monkey-patch idea sounds promising though.

Comment: I have raised this issue as: [bpo-41134: distutils.dir_util.copy_tree FileExistsError when updating symlinks](https://bugs.python.org/issue41134)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt: a shim for [`distutils.dir_util.copy_tree`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.dir_util.copy_tree) with monkeypatching `os.symlink`.

```
import contextlib
import os
import distutils.dir_util


@contextlib.contextmanager
def monkeypatch(object, name, patch):
    value_orig = getattr(object, name)
    setattr(object, name, patch)
    yield object
    setattr(object, name, value_orig)


def copy_tree(src, dst, **kwargs):
    stdlib_symlink = os.symlink

    def _symlink(src, dst, **kwargs):
        try:
            stdlib_symlink(src, dst, **kwargs)
        except FileExistsError as err:
            pass

    with monkeypatch(distutils.dir_util.os, 'symlink', _symlink):
        distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(src, dst, **kwargs)
```

This version of `_symlink` function will ignore any errors occurring on symlink attempts. You can write your own that will recreate the symlink, something like

```
def _symlink(src, dst, **kwargs):
    try:
        stdlib_symlink(src, dst, **kwargs)
    except FileExistsError as err:
        os.remove(dst)
        stdlib_symlink(src, dst)
```